# How to escape special characters in SQL strings from Delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2009

How to escape the special characters when executing an SQL query, when it is executed from Delphi using TADOQuery or TADOCommand etc..

For example the "scope operator".

Query looks like this.

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO supervisor
```

Thanks & Regards,
Pavan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not work with Delphi for a while, so far I remember a few tricks:

1. Set ParamCheck = False;
2. Run queries with connection.Execute(SQL);